# Como regresar un registro que contiene varios valores separados por coma

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo esta tabla en la base de datos:

```
Tabla de Ejemplo:
id  - registro - valor
1   - compras  - 1,2,6
2   - ventas   - 3,4
3   - deudas   - 5
```

Quiero hacer una consulta en donde yo envíe sólo el numero `3` y me traiga el registro 2 en este ejemplo.

Probe con `IN` y no lo hace, lo probe con `CONTAINS` y tampoco lo hace.

¿Que debo hacer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Query buscando un valor separado por comas

Hay varias alternativas:

1. La función [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) devuelve el índice en el cual un `string` se encuentra dentro de una `lista de strings` (separados por coma).

   ```
   select * from tabla where find_in_set('3',valor) > 0;
   ```
2. Agregando una coma antes y después del campo, para garantizar que *todos* los valores estén rodeados por comas (incluso el primero y el último). De esa forma, podemos usar [`like`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

   ```
   select * from tabla where concat( ',', valor, ',') like '%,3,%';
   ```
3. Usando [expresiones regulares](http://regular-expressions.info/) y el operador [`regexp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

   ```
   select * from tabla where valor regexp '(,|^)3(,|$)';
   ```

---

### Forma recomendada de hacerlo

Recomiendo, bajo todo punto de vista, no concatenar diferentes valores dentro de un mismo campo. En cambio, usar una estructura como la siguiente:

> ```
> ╔════╦══════════╦═══════╗
> ║ id ║ registro ║ valor ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
> ║  1 ║  compras ║   1   ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
> ║  1 ║  compras ║   2   ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
> ║  1 ║  compras ║   6   ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
> ║  2 ║  ventas  ║   3   ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
> ║  2 ║  ventas  ║   4   ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
> ║  3 ║  deudas  ║   5   ║
> ╚════╩══════════╩═══════╝
> ```

Esta estructura te va a facilitar cualquier operación que quieras hacer, y es la forma en la que una tabla relacional y el motor de la base de datos fue diseñado para usar. De esta forma, lógicamente es muchísimo más sencillo y rápido:

```sql
select * from tabla where valor = 3;
```

Y yendo un paso más lejos, podríamos normalizar la base para no tener tantos valores duplicados ocupando espacio por demás. Sería una estructura como la siguiente:

> ```
>  Tabla: principal               Tabla: nombresRegistros
> ╔════╦══════════╦═══════╗      ╔══════════╦═════════════════╗
> ║ id ║ registro ║ valor ║      ║ registro ║ registro_nombre ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣      ╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
> ║  1 ║     1    ║   1   ║      ║     1    ║     compras     ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣      ╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
> ║  1 ║     1    ║   2   ║      ║     2    ║      ventas     ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣      ╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
> ║  1 ║     1    ║   6   ║      ║     3    ║      deudas     ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣      ╚══════════╩═════════════════╝
> ║  2 ║     2    ║   3   ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
> ║  2 ║     2    ║   4   ║
> ╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
> ║  3 ║     3    ║   5   ║
> ╚════╩══════════╩═══════╝
> ```

Incluso, si quisieras obtener el formato con el que venías trabajando a partir de esta estructura, se obtendría con el siguiente query:

```sql
select id, registro_nombre, group_concat(principal.valor) as valor
from principal
left join nombresRegistros
on principal.registro = nombresRegistros.registro
group by id;
```

Esta es la forma en la que mejor podrás gestionar una base de datos.

Answer (score 2):

Si es una cadena lo que guardas en la columna valor, podrías usar la cláusula `LIKE` de sql

```
SELECT * FROM tu_tabla WHERE valor LIKE '%3%';
```

Lo que te devolvera los registros que contengan un 3 en la columna valor.

Comment: Es cierto @Mariano, utilizandolo sólo como dice Juan funciona perfectamente.

Comment: No, esto puede traer muchos falsos resultados, que tal los renglones que tienen el valor 13, 23, 30 hasta 39 , y etc. no puedes buscar todo lo que contiene una cifra, ya que es un subset de cualquier otra cosa que no empata

Comment: Lo siento amigo juan pero asi no funciona tampoco porque si tengo un registro que contenga 30 o 300 o 31 lo devuelve igual